# When positioning a div with relative positioning, is there a way to make the next div "flow" up to where the previous div now sits?

Tags: html, css

As an arbitrary example, if I have two `div`s with an image in between then as so,

```
<div class="section1">
        <h2>Stuff in section one</h2>
</div>
<img src="../img/logo.png" class='myimg'>
<div class="section1">
        <h2>Stuff in section two</h2>
</div>

<div class="section2">
    <div class="container"> 
        <h2 style="color:white">Stuff in section one</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

And say I want to display that image as a block, and adjust it upwards by 20 pixels.

```
.myimg{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Works fine, but now the `section2` div starts where the image *should* have been -- 20px below where it actually is.

Is there a way to make the next element (`section2` in the case) "aware" of a relatively positioned element that came before, so that it starts where that element actually ends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative top margin instead:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/n3tbf9ro

```
.myimg{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Or get rid of the bottom margin on the previous element:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/lsnlxk8i

```
.section1 :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```